# VBA Alternative to PHP SMTP Validation

Tags: php, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, email-validation

OK, So I know there are tonnes of questions about performing SMTP validation and the vast majority in using PHP or some other script. I have spent 2 days reading through as many as possible but I cannot find quite what I need.

So my question is this: Is there a VBA script alternative to these PHP ones that I can use in MS Access 2010 in conjunction with a form, button and a table to perform this SMTP level email validation, which then dumps the replies into another table?

P.S. I have already used expression validation to weed out obvious false addresses.

EDIT: Just in case someone asks, I am doing this to INVALIDATE as many genuine false emails as possible prior to submitting a list of potential valid emails to a 3rd party for further cleansing and updating.

Answer (score 0):

If you were thinking of a script that uses the SMTP verb `VRFY` to "validate" email addresses then that would just be a waste of time. `VRFY` (and `EXPN`) are almost universally configured to provide meaningless responses (if any) these days (ref: [here](http://www.spamresource.com/2007/01/whatever-happened-to-vrfy.html) and elsewhere).

If you had something else in mind (short of a script to spam every address and see which ones bounce) then please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I've seen a few people mention that VRFY and RCPT TO are useless, if this is the case it makes me wonder what the value of some of these 3rd party services is. A significant part of their validation is often described as being SMTP diagnostics as well as reverse DSN lookup and MX lookup. So why can't the average user script and test this themselves if they can? I want to invalidate as many actual fake addresses as possible, taking the remaining potential email addresses to a service such as QAS. Given the fees of this and similar services, it makes sense to do as much as you can yourself first